# How can you verify if a JWT is still valid?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jwt

I want to make a call every X amount of minutes from the client side to see if the JWT is still valid. I'm not sure how to do this in nodeJS. If I'm already authorized, how can i check if I'm *still* authorized.

Comment: I wouldn't do that at a set time interval - it should rather be done on every request that needs auth.

Comment: I am checking for inactivity. If the token has expired due to inactivity i want to send the application back to the login page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An elegant solution to handle token expiration is when you set the token(in `LocalStorage` or store(redux), or both) is also to have an Async function that runs exactly when the token expires. Something like this:

```
const logUserOut = token =>{
    setTimeout(()=> MyLogoutFunction(), token.expiresIn)
}
```

This way you make sure that the user won't be logged when the token is no longer valid.

Comment: if the user refreshes the page, the timer stops and the token will be stored forever, how do I solve this?

Comment: Usually this is done server side, and every time the users starts the application (by refreshing or opening for the first time) a request of validation is sended from the client to verify the JWT's validity.

Answer (score 8):

You can have your client side decode the JWT and check an `expiry` field and compare it with system time.

eg.

```
  isExpired: (token) => {
    if (token && jwt.decode(token)) {
      const expiry = jwt.decode(token).exp;
      const now = new Date();
      return now.getTime() > expiry * 1000;
    }
    return false;
```

you can use `npm install jsonwebtoken` or some other npm package on the client side to do this

Comment: and call this function every few seconds using setInterval or so? this is not a performance issue?

Comment: you use it in HOC same way you check your store for authentication status.

Answer (score 1):

Create and endpoint that verifies the token is valid. You can use the the jsonwebtoken package.

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

const verifyToken = (req, res) => {
  const token = req.headers.authorization;
  jwt.verify(token, SECRET_KEY, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(401).send();
    }
    // can do something with the decoded data
  })
}

router.post('/verify-token', verifyToken);
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a better option with promise to check if my token is valid

```
    jwt.verify(token,key,(err,result)=>{
    if(err){
        if(err.name == "TokenExpiredError"){
            console.log("Expired") //This case is when token expired
        }
        else{
            console.log(err.name) //Any other case
        }
    }
    else{
        //Here code for your promise using 'result' when token is Valid
    }
})
```

EDIT: this code is OK if you don't use the JWT for security reason, only if you use it to public stuff.
since this request is show to user if it valid or not, and if not why.
I'm using it only to understand if object is still available for other reason. (and it's OK to be public)

Comment: People who are reading this, if you use HMAC algorithm you should not be using the above code on the client side. You should not reveal your key publicly.